# Burning iso to usb in ubuntu on mac hardware

Tags: xubuntu, usb-drive, mac, iso

I am trying to "burn" (yes I know thats not the right term) an iso for xubuntu onto my usb pendrive. I am on mac hardware but I have ubuntu installed and I would like to be able to do it without having to boot into mac os x. I have tried unetbootin and `sudo dd if=xubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb1` but none of them worked. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Additional info:
I am on an intel mac, not one of those old powerpc things. It is a mid 2012 (I think) macbook pro

Answer (score 0):

All you need is run Startup Disk Creator https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/usb-creator-gtk/ and feed it with image file (in your case xubuntu.iso).